# Mount Windows share in RHEL, while managing NTFS permissions on the windows side

Tags: windows, redhat, ntfs

I have a requirement to mount a Windows share (\windows1\share$) on a RHEL server (RHEL1).  To mount the windows share, I'm using an Active Directory service account.  The service account has share\NTFS permissions over share$.

I would like to mount the Windows share on the RHEL box, and have the availability to manipulate individual AD user or group permissions on the actual Windows server.

I am able to mount the share and am able to access the path from various locations, using RHEL server address.  The issue is that no matter how the permissions are setup on the Windows server, the service account permissions overwrite them.

I'm assuming since the share is being mounted via a service account, that particular service account's permissions are taking effect when accessing the path.

Hope this makes sense.